# SJCL not concatenating bit arrays

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, bitarray, rncryptor, sjcl

I am trying to use RNCryptor-JS which uses SJCL but for some reason, SJCL bit array concatenation does not seem to work.

```
var SALT_SIZE = 64/8;

var plaintext = "Hello, World!";

var password = "myPassword";

function keyForPassword(password, salt){
    // Using CryptoJS for pbkdf2, aes, sha256, and random word arrays
    var pbkdf2_key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        password,
        salt,
        {
          keySize: 256/32,
          iterations: 1000,
          hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256
        }
      );
    return pbkdf2_key;
}

var encryption_salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(SALT_SIZE);
var encryption_key = keyForPassword(password, encryption_salt);

var hmac_salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(SALT_SIZE);
var hmac_key = keyForPassword(password, hmac_salt);

var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);

var version = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits("03");
var options = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits("01");

var message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(version, iv);
message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, encryption_salt);
message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, hmac_salt);
message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, iv);

// Progressive cipher
var aesEncryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createEncryptor(encryption_key, {iv: iv});
var ciphertext = aesEncryptor.process(plaintext);

message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, ciphertext);    

var hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(hmac_key).encrypt(message);

var encrypted_data = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, hmac);
var output = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(encrypted_data);

console.log(output);
```

When I log the output of `message` after the first set of `sjcl.bitArray.concat` is done, all that returns is the first concatenation of `version` and `iv`. The final hex output is just that first concatenation and `hmac` concatenated. This reinforces my suspicion that it might be CryptoJS's fault because the output concatenation works and is between two sjcl variables.

I tried using SJCL random bit arrays but had some trouble. SJCL's generator, `prng`, did not work when using

```
new sjcl.prng.randomWords(32/4);
```

or

```
new sjcl.prng(32/4);
```

And `sjcl.random.randomWords` does not seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CryptoJS ([`WordArray`](https://github.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/tree/3.1.2/src/core.js#L145)) and SJCL ([`bitArray`](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/bitArray.js)) have different internal representations of data. You can't simply concatenate them.

The easiest way would be probably to encode it into an intermediate format such as Hex and let the other side decode into its internal format:

```
message = sjcl.bitArray.concat(version, sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(iv.toString()));
```

`WordArray#toString()` automatically uses Hex encoding. You would have to do this for all lines, but this is a little overkill, since you can concatenate Hex strings as strings:

```
message = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits("03" + iv + encryption_salt + hmac_salt + iv);
```

This should work as expected, because adding a `WordArray` such as `iv` to a string automatically calls its `toString()` function which in turn produces a big-endian hex-encoded string.

I wonder why you're using `iv` twice. Perhaps you meant `options` on one of them.

---

What needs to change:

```
function convert(wordArray){
    return sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(wordArray.toString());
}
var message = "0301" + encryption_salt + hmac_salt + iv;

var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, encryption_key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext;

message += ciphertext;
message = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(message);

var hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(convert(hmac_key)).encrypt(message);

var encrypted_data = sjcl.bitArray.concat(message, hmac);
var output = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(encrypted_data);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yeah that was supposed to be options. Forgot to change from debugging. Thanks for the solution. That part works, but now ciphertext is not being included and `hmac` comes right after `iv`. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Forgot to scroll down. The same applies to the other functions. You need to convert the representation.

Comment: Tried to apply the `toBits` concatenation with `message + ciphertext` and `message + hmac` toward the end with various combinations of string formatting but that keeps coming up with strings with many 0's. Encoding is not my bag. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You would need to keep track of which format `message` is currently in. `+` makes only sense if it is a string, but won't work if it is a bitArray like in your question. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Update: progressive cipher was not being finalized. Also was able to concatenate everything using `message = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(message) + ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` and then `sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(message)`. The `message + hmac` at the bottom  didn't need it. The whole hex output is now complete. Just need to find out why the HMAC's don't line up. Thank you for the assistance again!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"HMAC's don't line up"*, but I think I answered your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in the Python RNCryptor the HMAC did not pass verification. Was a problem with the pbkdf2 iteration length matching. Everything is working now! Thank again for your awesome answers.